# iteration using it.chain

Tags: python, pandas, function, iteration

I'm stuck on returning the result from the function which is checking samples for A/B test and gave the result. The calculation is correct, but somehow I'm getting the result twice. The code and output below.

```py
def test (sample1, sample2):
    
    for i in it.chain (range(len(sample1)), range(len(sample2))):
        
        alpha = .05
           
        difference = (sample1['step_conversion'][i] - sample2['step_conversion'][i])/100
            
        if (i > 0):
            
           
            p_combined = (sample1['unq_user'][i] + sample2['unq_user'][i]) / (sample1['unq_user'][i-1] + sample2['unq_user'][i-1])
            
           
            z_value = difference / mth.sqrt(
            p_combined * (1 - p_combined) * (1 / sample1['unq_user'][i-1] + 1 / sample2['unq_user'][i-1]))
            
         
            distr = st.norm(0, 1)
            
            p_value = (1 - distr.cdf(abs(z_value))) * 2

            print( sample1['event_name'][i], 'p-value: ', p_value)

            if p_value < alpha:
                print('Deny H0')
            else:
                print('Accept H0')
        
    return
```

So I need the result in output just once (tagged in the box), but I get it twice from both samples.
[image: output]

Comment: You get the results twice, because `it.chain (range(len(sample1)), range(len(sample2)))` creates an iterator of two ranges, and each range is the same (assuming sample1 and sample2 have the same length).

Answer (score 0):

When using Pandas dataframes, you should avoid most for loops, and use the standard vectorised approach. Use NumPy where applicable.

First, I've reset the indexes (indices) of the dataframes, to be sure `.loc` can be used with a standard numerical index.

```
sample1 = sample1.reset_index()
sample2 = sample2.reset_index()
```

The below does what I *think* you for loop does.
I can't test it, and without a clear description, example dataframes and expected outcome, it is anyone's guess if the code below does what you want. But it may get close, and mostly serves as an example of the vectorised approach.

```
import numpy as np

difference = (sample1['step_conversion'] - sample2['step_conversion']) / 100

n = len(sample1)
# Note that Pandas uses `n` as the highest *valid* index when using `.loc`, `n-1` is one lower
p_combined = ((sample1.loc[1:, 'unq_user'] + sample2.loc[1:, 'unq_user']).reset_index(drop=True) /
              (sample1.loc[:n-1, 'unq_user'] + sample2.loc[:n-1, 'unq_user'])).reset_index(drop=True)

z_value = difference / np.sqrt(
              p_combined * (1 - p_combined) * (
                  1 / sample1.loc[:n-1, 'unq_user'] + 1 / sample2.loc[:n-1, 'unq_user']))


distr = st.norm(0, 1)  # ??
        
p_value = (1 - distr.cdf(np.abs(z_value))) * 2

sample1['p_value'] = p_value
print(sample1)

# The below prints a list of True values for elements for which the condition is valid.
# You can also use e.g. `print(sample1[p_value < alpha])`.
alpha = 0.05
print('Deny H0:')
print(p_value < alpha)
print('Accept H0:')
print(p_value > alpha)
```

No for loop needed, and for a large dataframe, the above will be notably faster.

Note that the `.reset_index(drop=True)` is a bit ugly. But if that is not there, Pandas will divide the two dataframes by equal indices, which is not what we want. This way, that is avoided.